# Unable to Create New RDS Database Instance in AWS: Easy Create Not Responding After Pressing 'Create Database'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I currently have an existing RDS database instance in AWS that is in an incompatible network state. I am attempting to create a new RDS database instance to migrate all the information from the existing instance. However, when I use the 'Easy Create' option in the AWS Management Console, specify the engine type as MySQL, choose the free tier option, and click on 'Create Database', nothing happens. The page does not respond, and the new database instance is not created.

I attempted to create a VPC along with associated subnets,but still does not work

Comment: Perhaps try with a different browser, different computer or different network connection (eg home vs office vs tethered via phone)? These will help you identify what is causing the problem (and whether the problem is within AWS or outside of it).

Comment: I tried using multiple browsers like internet explorer on my laptop ,firefox and google on my phone,including creating a hotspot from my phone to my laptop but i still get the same result,i figured out that i do not have a subnet group so i tried creating one with this configuration:3 subnets from 3 different availability zones,us-west-2a,us-west-2b,us-west-2c in total having 6 subnets ,but if i press the create button ,it is not responding

Comment: could it be because i deleted the default vpc and subnets?

Comment: It is quite unusual for the browser to hang, which is why I recommended using a different browser, etc. If you created a new VPC and configured RDS to use that new VPC, it should be fine. However, deleting the default VPC can lead to problems with some services. You can recreate it, see: [Default VPCs - Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/default-vpc.html#create-default-vpc)

Comment: I deleted the default vpc,because I was being charged for using ipv4,so I deleted it and recreate a new one which has ipv4 and ipv6 cidrs with ipv6 only subnets,but if I press the create rds button it still does not work,maybe the cause is that I use easy create option instead of standard create,but that would cost money

Comment: Are you saying that you are launching the RDS instance in subnet that only has IPv6 addresses? That might be the cause of the problem. Can you try (briefly) launching in a subnet that has IPv4 to see whether it behaves differently? FYI, a VPC does not have any charges. You will only be charged for resources that use the VPC (eg NAT Gateway, EC2 instances, Load Balancer, Data Transfer to the Internet).

Comment: I created an RDS instance with subnets that have both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. While it initially worked, I noticed that I'm being charged again. Looking at the bill, it indicates charges for the VPC ($1.10), specifically $0.005 per in-use public IPv4 address per hour for 220.899 hours, and for the Relational Database service ($0.18). I thought I could avoid this charge,as for resources i only use rds

Comment: If you use an Amazon RDS database with the setting of `Publicly Accessible = No`, then it will not assign a Public IP address. The database will only be accessible within the VPC via its DNS Name and private IP address, which is typical of application configurations.